# What is the purpose of the CreateSilverlight.js?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am trying to get out of browser support working for my Silverlight application and keep bumping into examples that reference CreateSilverlight.js. Looks like it has a variety of options to configure the the Silverlight experience for the end user.

Is this a Microsoft javascript file for Silverlight? If so, where would I find it? I would have expected it to have already been added to my Silverlight project.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateSilverlight.js is the Silverlight runtime boostrapper.  It should be in any new Slivelight project you create in Visual Studio, as long as you've loaded the Silverlight SDK.

Comment: I have the Silverlight 3 SDK installed ... but this file isn't available when I create a new Silverlight application in either VS2008 or VS2010.